# Escaping characters in AWS SSM command

Tags: bash, cassandra, escaping, aws-ssm

I can't get my escape characters correct for an AWS SSM command with double quotes inside. Here's the last attempt:

```
aws ssm send-command --instance-ids "i-012345678" --document-name "AWS-RunShellScript" --query "Command.CommandId"  --output text --parameters commands='["sudo su","cd /opt/cassandra/bin","cqlsh -e \"select * from system_schema.keyspaces;"\"]'
```

Essentially it's the last command, the double quotes around the `cqlsh` command that I can't escape from erroring. Have tried to store it in variable and echo but neither works. Also looked at answers below.

[aws ssm send-command not working with special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66459317/aws-ssm-send-command-not-working-with-special-characters)
[Send multiple lines of script to EC2 instance from PowerShell SSM cmdlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60641044/send-multiple-lines-of-script-to-ec2-instance-from-powershell-ssm-cmdlets)

Comment: Try `"\"` to  `\""`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the documentation,

- [v1 docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ssm/send-command.html)
- [v2 docs](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ssm/send-command.html)
- [quoting and escaping rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-parameters-quoting-strings.html)

> You do not need to escape double quotation marks embedded in the JSON string, as they are being treated literally.

Could you instead try the below?

```
aws ssm send-command \
--instance-ids "i-012345678" \
--document-name "AWS-RunShellScript" \
--query "Command.CommandId" \
--output text \
--parameters commands='[{"sudo su","/opt/cassandra/bin/cqlsh -e \"SELECT * FROM system_schema.keyspaces;\""}]'
```